# Pick one of a list in a String Array in Swift3

Tags: arrays, swift, string, random

I have a question. How can i do it, that my array picks randomizely a String from the list?

I want to pick random one of these products of the list?

My thought was, i can do it again with an array, but I get this error:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

My Code is :

```
private func randomProduct() -> Int {
let myArray1 = ["Nintendo Classic Mini NES", "Microsoft Office 2016 Home and Business", "Rubie's Deluxe Muscle Chest Batman Child", "Giro Dime", "Varta Powersports AGM 12V 12Ah 512014010A514", "Pohl-Boskamp Gelomyrtol Forte", "Panasonic ES-LV9N-S803", "Traxxas X-Maxx (77076-4)", "GoPro HERO 4", "Bose Lifestyle 650", "WMF Function 4 Kochtopf-Set 4-teilig", "Microsoft Surface Book", "Hewlett-Packard HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw (B4A22A)", "Apple iPhone 7", "X-lite X-403GT Elegance", "Denon AVR-X3300W", "Hasbro Spiel des Lebens Banking", "Avent SCD 630/26", "Ray-Ban Aviator Metal RB3025"]
return Int(myArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray1.count)))])!
```

Hope you can help me!

Thx a lot!

Comment: None of the strings in your array are convertible to `Int`...

Comment: To add to that, you probably want to return a `String`, and get rid of the `Int` in the `return` line.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you want to use the random number Int as the index to find your **String** within the array. Then you return the string. So, just make a couple changes:

```
private func randomProduct() -> String { // Return String, not Int
    let myArray1 = ["Nintendo Classic Mini NES", "Microsoft Office 2016 Home and Business", "Rubie's Deluxe Muscle Chest Batman Child", "Giro Dime", "Varta Powersports AGM 12V 12Ah 512014010A514", "Pohl-Boskamp Gelomyrtol Forte", "Panasonic ES-LV9N-S803", "Traxxas X-Maxx (77076-4)", "GoPro HERO 4", "Bose Lifestyle 650", "WMF Function 4 Kochtopf-Set 4-teilig", "Microsoft Surface Book", "Hewlett-Packard HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw (B4A22A)", "Apple iPhone 7", "X-lite X-403GT Elegance", "Denon AVR-X3300W", "Hasbro Spiel des Lebens Banking", "Avent SCD 630/26", "Ray-Ban Aviator Metal RB3025"]
    return myArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray1.count)))] // Remove the Int()
}
```